# Error: could not find the function crs

Tags: coordinate-system, r, coordinates, modelling

```
library(sp)
coordinates(acg) <- ~lon+lat
```

> Error in `coordinates<-`(`*tmp*`, value = ~lon + lat) :    setting
>   coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where they have already
>   been set

```
crs(acg) <- crs(wrld_simpl)
```

> Error in crs(wrld_simpl) : could not find function "crs"

Comment: Please use words to describe what you are attempting, including the software release and a description to your data. Code-only and code and error message jumbled do not provide enough content for others to find your question, even if an answer is possible.

Answer (score 4):

**First message error:**

> setting coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where **they have already been set**

You can't set coordinates again if they are already set.

**Second message error:**

> Error in crs(wrld_simpl) : could not find function "crs"

The function is `CRS`, not `crs`

*I highly recommend reading error messages before posting questions with neither header nor body*

Comment: or it could be `raster::crs`. The `sp::CRS` function won't work like in the question.

Comment: Also `sf` is a more up to date spatial package that I would recommend switching to

Comment: @Spacedman completely agreed. But since he called `sp` library, probably don't know anything about `raster` one.

Comment: hence the right thing to do is to not answer but to vote "close" as unclear and ask for clarification in comments - I don't know why this answer has so many upvotes. Sorry.